# print not accepted in task definition in SBT 0.13?

Tags: sbt

I'm using SBT `0.13.1`.

**project/build.properties** is as follows:

```
sbt.version=0.13.1
```

Executing `sbt about` prints out the following:

```
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/project
[info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
[sbt-0-13-1]> about
[info] This is sbt 0.13.1
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/}sbt-0-13-1 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.4-RC1
[info] Available Plugins: com.typesafe.sbt.SbtGit, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtProguard, growl.GrowlingTests, np.Plugin, net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.3
```

With the following task - `hello` - in `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4-RC1"

lazy val hello = taskKey[Unit]("An example task")

hello := {
  print("Sleeping for a sec...")
  println("done.")
}
```

...and `reload`, sbt reports `[error] Type error in expression`:

```
[sbt-0-13-1]> reload
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/project
/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/build.sbt:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("Sleeping for a sec...")
 required: sbt.TaskKey[String]
  print("Sleeping for a sec...")
        ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

When I change `print` to `println` the task is defined correctly.

```
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? r
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/project
[info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
[sbt-0-13-1]> hello
Sleeping for a sec...
done.
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 4, 2014 10:31:43 AM
```

Is `print` not accepted in task definition?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: @Schleichardt I added few more details about the environment. Are you using sbt 0.13.1?

Comment: Thank you, but I still can't repproduce. I use SBT 0.13.1. Can you remove all your SBT plugins and then try again?

Comment: You're right! Thanks for the hint! The `hello` task works with `print` when `sbt -Dsbt.global.base=/tmp/so`. Wonder what might be breaking it.

Comment: Can you post an answer which SBT plugin breaks the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [schleichardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1575096/schleichardt) I could finally find out what has caused the issue of not accepting `print` in the `hello` task.

It turned out that with [the sbt-dependency-graph plugin](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) in the global configuration directory, i.e. `~/.sbt/0.13/` (or a directory specified by `sbt.global.base`), sbt couldn't initialize the task and hence the error.

```
$ cat plugins/sbt-dependency-graph.sbt
addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.7.4")

$ cat sbt-dependency-graph.sbt
net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings
```

To reproduce, see the following sbt session starting with `print` (**not** `println`) in `build.sbt` and **empty** global configuration directory:

```
jacek:~/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1
$ tree
.
├── build.sbt
└── project
    └── build.properties

1 directory, 2 files

jacek:~/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1
$ cat build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.10.4-RC1"

lazy val hello = taskKey[Unit]("An example task")

hello := {
  print("Sleeping for a sec...")
  println("done.")
}

jacek:~/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1
$ sbt -Dsbt.global.base=/tmp/so
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.1 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
    confs: [default]
    43 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (12646kB/154ms)
Getting Scala 2.10.3 (for sbt)...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (24447kB/204ms)
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/project/}sbt-0-13-1-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
> hello
Sleeping for a sec...done.
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 4, 2014 1:35:22 PM
```

It works so far.

Create the files for [the sbt-dependency-graph plugin](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) in the global configuration directory.

```
jacek:/tmp/so
$ cat plugins/sbt-dependency-graph.sbt
addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.7.4")

jacek:/tmp/so
$ cat sbt-dependency-graph.sbt
net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings
```

...and `reload`.

```
> reload
[info] Loading global plugins from /private/tmp/so/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/tmp/so/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/project/}sbt-0-13-1-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/build.sbt:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("Sleeping for a sec...")
 required: sbt.TaskKey[String]
  print("Sleeping for a sec...")
        ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

When `print` changes to `println` and `(r)etry`, it works fine again.

```
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? r
[info] Loading global plugins from /private/tmp/so/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/project
[info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
> hello
Sleeping for a sec...
done.
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 4, 2014 1:43:59 PM
```

Comment: This is kind of a long answer to say that a plugin (`sbt-dependency-graph`) introduces an identifier that conflicts with something from Predef (`print`).  Whether the plugin is global or local to a project shouldn't matter.