# Why does sbt throw "value enablePlugins is not a member of sbt.Project" exception?

Tags: sbt

I am trying to enable a custom AutoPlugin in a project using SBT version 0.13.5. When I try to enable the plugin in my `build.sbt` via:

```
val aProject = project.in(file("foo")).enablePlugins(MyAutoPlugin)
```

I get the following error when trying to start SBT from the command line:

```
value enablePlugins is not a member of sbt.Project
... (big stack trace) ...
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

When I look at the source code for sbt.Project I see that `enablePlugins` [is defined](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Project.scala#L168). What is going on here?

**Edit**: when I remove the call to `enablePlugins` I can successfully start an SBT session. Running `> about` confirms that SBT version is 0.13.5.

**Edit 3**: I found that when I publish plugins to Sonatype with a version in the format of "2014.06.26-1-SNAPSHOT" that SBT fails to load with above error. However, if I change the format to include a single letter after "-1", then SBT loads. So this version format works: "2014.06.26-1a-SNAPSHOT". I discovered this because I found resolving to locally published plugins seemed to work fine (for all but one plugin that never worked), while resolving to the exact same plugins published to Sonatype caused the error. When I published locally, I always added a letter to the version.

**Edit 2**: full output of SBT log:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/markschaake/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[debug] 
[debug] Initial source changes: 
[debug]     removed:Set()
[debug]     added: Set()
[debug]     modified: Set()
[debug] Removed products: Set()
[debug] External API changes: API Changes: Set()
[debug] Modified binary dependencies: Set()
[debug] Initial directly invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] 
[debug] Sources indirectly invalidated by:
[debug]     product: Set()
[debug]     binary dep: Set()
[debug]     external source: Set()
[debug] All initially invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] Copy resource mappings: 
[debug]     
[debug] Other repositories:
[debug]     FileRepository(publish-m2-local,FileConfiguration(true,None),Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(), artifactPatterns=List(/Users/markschaake/.m2/repository/[organisation]/[module](_[scalaVersion])(_[sbtVersion])/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=true, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false))
[debug] Default repositories:
[debug]     Raw(ProjectResolver(inter-project, mapped: ))
[debug]     URLRepository(typesafe-ivy-releases,Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=List(http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false))
[debug]     URLRepository(sbt-plugin-releases,Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=List(http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false))
[debug]     FileRepository(local,FileConfiguration(true,None),Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=List(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false))
[debug]     public: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
[debug] Using inline dependencies specified in Scala.
[debug] deducing auto plugins based on known facts Set(Atom(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin)) and clauses Clauses(List(Clause(Atom(sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin),Set(Atom(sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin))), Clause(Atom(sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin),Set(Atom(sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin))), Clause(Atom(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin),Set(Atom(sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin))), Clause(Atom(sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin),Set(Atom(sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin))), Clause(Atom(sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin),Set(Atom(sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin)))))
[debug]   :: deduced result: Matched(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin,sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin,sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin,sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin)
[debug] sorting: ns: List(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin)
[debug]   :: sorting:: found: List(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin) not found List(sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin)
[debug]   :: sorting:: found: List(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin) not found List(sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin)
[debug]   :: sorting:: found: List(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin) not found List(sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin)
[debug]   :: sorting:: found: List(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin) not found List()
[debug]   :: sorted deduced result: List(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin)
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/markschaake/ai2/git/ai2-parsers/project/project
[debug] Running task... Cancel: sbt.TaskCancellationStrategy$Null$@7727d0c5, check cycles: false
[debug] 
[debug] Initial source changes: 
[debug]     removed:Set()
[debug]     added: Set()
[debug]     modified: Set()
[debug] Removed products: Set()
[debug] External API changes: API Changes: Set()
[debug] Modified binary dependencies: Set()
[debug] Initial directly invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] 
[debug] Sources indirectly invalidated by:
[debug]     product: Set()
[debug]     binary dep: Set()
[debug]     external source: Set()
[debug] All initially invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] Copy resource mappings: 
[debug]     
[debug] deducing auto plugins based on known facts Set(Atom(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin)) and clauses Clauses(List(Clause(Atom(sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin),Set(Atom(sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin))), Clause(Atom(sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin),Set(Atom(sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin))), Clause(Atom(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin),Set(Atom(sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin))), Clause(Atom(sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin),Set(Atom(sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin))), Clause(Atom(sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin),Set(Atom(sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin)))))
[debug]   :: deduced result: Matched(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin,sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin,sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin,sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin)
[debug] sorting: ns: List(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin)
[debug]   :: sorting:: found: List(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin) not found List(sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin)
[debug]   :: sorting:: found: List(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin) not found List(sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin)
[debug]   :: sorting:: found: List(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin) not found List(sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin)
[debug]   :: sorting:: found: List(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin) not found List()
[debug]   :: sorted deduced result: List(sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin)
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/markschaake/ai2/git/ai2-parsers/project
[debug] Running task... Cancel: sbt.TaskCancellationStrategy$Null$@7727d0c5, check cycles: false
[debug] 
[debug] Initial source changes: 
[debug]     removed:Set()
[debug]     added: Set()
[debug]     modified: Set()
[debug] Removed products: Set()
[debug] External API changes: API Changes: Set()
[debug] Modified binary dependencies: Set()
[debug] Initial directly invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] 
[debug] Sources indirectly invalidated by:
[debug]     product: Set()
[debug]     binary dep: Set()
[debug]     external source: Set()
[debug] All initially invalidated sources: Set()
[debug] Copy resource mappings: 
[debug]     
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.checkError(Eval.scala:343)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.compileAndLoad(Eval.scala:165)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalCommon(Eval.scala:135)
    at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalDefinitions(Eval.scala:109)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateDefinitions(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:197)
    at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateSbtFile(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:99)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:507)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:502)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:501)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:501)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadSettings$1$2.apply(Load.scala:500)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadSettings$1$2.apply(Load.scala:500)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.Load$.loadSettings$1(Load.scala:500)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$expand$1(Load.scala:523)
    at sbt.Load$.loadSettings(Load.scala:528)
    at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSbtFiles$1(Load.scala:464)
    at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad$1(Load.scala:475)
    at sbt.Load$.loadTransitive(Load.scala:478)
    at sbt.Load$.loadProjects$1(Load.scala:418)
    at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:419)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:256)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:256)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:93)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:92)
    at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:143)
    at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:312)
    at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:264)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:260)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:251)
    at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:134)
    at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:37)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:473)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:467)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:467)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:95)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:179)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:100)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:93)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:66)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:66)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:49)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:33)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:25)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:57)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
```

Comment: Can you add an output content of the `about` command ?

Comment: Could you provide minimal working example reproducing this error?

Comment: Can you execute `sbt -Dsbt.global.base=/tmp/so` to cross out any global plugin that might interfere with sbt 0.13.5? Do you perhaps use `addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.7.4")` as a plugin? [There's at least one incident reported](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20873896/1305344) that caused some troubles similar to yours.

Comment: So I've upgraded our plugins to all be AutoPlugin, and everything works when I add plugins that are published locally (Resolver.defaultLocal). When I publish to sonatype and use Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots") one of the plugins causes SBT to downgrade and throw this error again. This offending plugin is wrapping sbt-scalriform 1.3.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the problem had to do with publishing to Sonatype snapshots repository and how SBT resolved the plugins.

I followed the recommendation from the [official SBT documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Bintray-For-Plugins.html) to publish to Bintray instead. I'm also only publishing releases (and not snapshots). Now everything works fine.

**Update**: a simple workaround is to add a dependency override for the SBT version in your `project/pugins.sbt`:

```
// project/plugins.sbt
dependencyOverrides += "org.scala-sbt" % "sbt" % "0.13.7"
```

Note: the version you provide should be the same as what is in your `project/build.properties` file.

Comment: update late 2016: problem still exists and workaround Mark mentions still valid

Answer (score 1):

Removing the ivy2 cache files work for me:

```
rm -r ~/.ivy2/
```

reference: https://github.com/scalapb/ScalaPB/issues/89

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the issue by using `project/Build.scala` for your build configuration instead of `build.sbt`.

The actual issue is detailed in [sbt/#1592](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1592) and [gatling-sbt/#29](https://github.com/gatling/gatling-sbt/issues/29)

Comment: However, please note that publishing plugins to Bintray is a much better fix for that issue. You don't need to move to `.scala` builds if you used `.sbt` + those plugins will be available for any SBT build project without relying on additional resolvers.